# Changing options menu/actionbar menu programatically for 3.0+

Tags: android, menu

In short, here's my question:

**Can option menus (shown in the actionbar) be modified programatically on android 3.0+?**

I have a wizard-style activity in which I use a ViewFlipper to switch between views, or steps.

The steps are: 1 -> 2 -> 3. Only the second screen (2) has a menu item, while the others don't. I have tried hanging on to the Menu reference ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)) and either removing/adding items or just hiding/showing them.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.mMenu = menu;
    
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    mMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Switch to the second screen ->

```
public void showNext(View v) {
    if (mVFlipper.getDisplayedChild() < (mVFlipper.getChildCount() - 1)) {
        mVFlipper.showNext();
        if (mVFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
            setTitle("Second screen");
            mMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on 2.2, but fails miserably on 4.1. Starting off with a visible MenuItem and hiding it later works. Starting off with an invisible menu item and showing it later -

Comment: in your onCreateOptionMenu code, do a check for the current page and only create the menuitem if the right page is displayed. then call invalidateOptionsMenu whenever the page changes.

if i remember correctly, there is a bug in Android's MenuItem code that doesn't toggle visibility correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved the problem in the meantime using a rather hack approach and have no time to test your suggestion now, but it seems that it's what I need (assuming it does what the documentation says). Will post it.

Comment: i'll post it as a solution and you can accept it if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in Android's MenuItem setVisible that causes problems when turning items back to visible.

In your onCreateOptionsMenu(), add a check to see if the displayed page needs the Menu, if it does, add the MenuItem. Then, call invalidateOptionsMenu() whenever the page changes. That will rebuild the Menu.

Comment: finally a reasonable solution! :) thank you toadzky!

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed by having the MenuItem be visible after onCreateOptionsMenu finishes and then hiding it from a callback called after onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.mMenu = menu;

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);        

    boolean dummyVal = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
        mMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);  
    } else {
        mMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    }

    return dummyVal;
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        if (mMenu != null) {
            mMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has this problem, I recommend trying toadzky's suggestion first: calling "invalidateOptionsMenu()".

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this issue, then I applied a small hack:

```
menu1.setEnabled(false);
menu1.setTitle("");
```

Then where you want to visible it again:

```
menu1.setEnabled(true);
menu1.setTitle("Okay"); //or you can set text according to your given updated values.
```